# For what complex values $z$ make the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{1+z^{n}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

This is my guess:

Since $z^{n}$ converges when $|z|<1$, the series in question must converge when $|z|>1$, since then $1>\frac{1}{|z|}$ and since $\frac{2}{1+z^{n}}<\frac{2}{z^{n}}$, the series converges by the comparison test.

Is this guess right though? Or am I wrong in some arguments?

Comment: This doesn't quite work because it doesn't make sense to talk about whether $z^n \lt 1+z^n$ for *complex* $z$.  You have to work with absolute values and it's not necessarily true that $|z^n| \lt |1+z^n|$.  So you have to do more work than that to get a bound.  A more careful variant on this argument can work.  You also need to state whether you have convergence if $|z| \leq 1$.

Comment: @RobertShore I don't think there is convergence when $|z|\leq 1$. Hmm... I want to use the comparison test with a geometric series but I am not sure what to do from there.

Comment: You're right about $|z| \leq 1$ but you need to explain why that's true.  As for $|z| \gt 1$, first fix $z$.  It has some specific absolute value $|z| = 1+\delta~ (\delta \gt 0)$.  Show that for large enough $n$, the $n$th term of the sum is smaller in absolute value than $c/(1+\delta)^n$ for some $c \gt 0$.  Then you're in good shape to use the comparison test.